# IIS behaviour: recycling application pools

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7

In IIS7 we are able to set on which time we want to recycle our application pools
[image]

Now we want to use the Time interval + the Specific time.
What's the behaviour of this.

Example:
*Our interval will be 48 houres (2880 minutes).
Our Specific time will be 03:00 AM.*

We hope it will run each 48 hours at 03:00 AM. But we're afraid it will run every time it is 03:00 AM. So each 24 hours. Is this the case or takes the specific time the regular time interval into account?

Answer (score 0):

How about a scheduled task that runs according to the time parameters that you've outlined above?

The command that the scheduled task runs will be:

```
APPCMD (command) (object-type) <identifier>
```

where APPPOOL is the object type you're interested in
and RECYCLE is the command you're interested in

To get help for each command use /?

Note: appcmd isn't in the path, you'll have to find it in %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\

IIS.NET page [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#HowToUse)